# TK "grid" and "grid remove"

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have TK application with several frames containing different widgets.
To hide a frame (and its content) I use *grid remove $frame*".
How can I achieve the resizing of the TK toplevel to the minimum needed geometry?

```
grid [ttk::frame .f ] -sticky nwse
grid [ttk::frame .f.f] -sticky nwse
foreach el {a b c d e f} {
 grid [label .f.f.$el -text "ELEM $el" ] -sticky nwse
}
update
after 2500
grid remove .f.f
```

What is necessary after "grid remove .f.f" to have a toplevel in a size without the labels?

Comment: I added these lines

  `grid [label .f.c]; update; destroy .f.c`

 after `grid remove` and it works. But think this is worse solution.

Additionally, after a manual resize of the toplevel, this does not work any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

wm geometry $toplevel {}

Regards,

jima

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't work (either with `remove` nor with `forget`). I have used `wm geometry . {}` since the variable $toplevel is not defined...

Answer (score 2):

While [`grid remove`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/grid.htm#M25) takes the widget out of the grid, it doesn't forget the information about how to lay that widget out (in case you want to add it back in at the same location, an occasionally useful operation). To really forget it entirely, you should use [`grid forget`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/grid.htm#M20) which removes the widget *and* drops its layout information.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how can I advice the TK gui to do a recalculation, even if the user did a manual modification of the size using the window manager. Lets say: a button to reset to original size.

Answer (score 0):

I am suprised wht *wm geometry $toplevel {}.* It redraws. Great.
But it does not solve my issue, but understand now the situation.

If a the toplevelFrame (the first and only frame in a toplevel) is removed from the grid, the toplevel is "empty" and not redrawn.

If the toplevel as at least to widgets/frames which are in the grid I can remove one and the redrawing is done.

In my example .e is a helper frame. No size no content.

```
package require Tk
grid [frame .e ]
grid [frame .f ] -sticky nwse
foreach el {a b c e f g h} {
    grid [label .f.$el -text "1ELEM $el" ] -sticky nwse
 }
update
after 1000
grid remove .f
```